# ValueError while using Pandas dataframe.iloc with complex lambda expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I`m trying to slice Pandas data frame using the lambda, like this:

```
print(df.iloc[lambda x: (M < x.index < M + 5) | (x.index % N == 0), :])
```

M and N are arbitrary integer variables.
However, I get an error that seems to be related to the lambda expression. Simplifying the expression to just one comparison works without any problems.

The error descripion:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas Index does not support the `a < x.index < b` form:

```
df.loc[((M < df.index) & (df.index < M+5)) | (df.index % N == 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
M=5
N=2
print(df.iloc[[i for i in df.index if ((M < i < M + 5) or (i % N == 0))],:])
```

Comment: Your solution works just as well as Corralein`s does, thanks